# How to send category name from Wordpress to Google Analytics Content Groups (universal tracking code)

Tags: universal-analytics

I want to enable content grouping in Google Analytics by submitting the category of my posts from within the tracking code.

A solution for GA's async version of the tracking code would look like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X']);
<?php 
if (is_single()){
    echo “_gaq.push(['_setPageGroup', 1, '".get_the_author()."']);\n”;
    $category = get_the_category();
    if ($category && !empty($category[0]->cat_name)){
        echo “_gaq.push([‘_setPageGroup’, 2, ‘”.$category[0]->cat_name.”‘]);\n”;
    }
}
?>
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

How can I set up the same functionality using GA's universal tracking code?

Thanks!

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic GA syntax:

```
_gaq.push(['_setPageGroup', '<Index Number>', '<Group Name>']);
```

UA syntax:

```
ga('set', 'contentGroup<Index Number>', '<Group Name>');
```

So in your case it should/would/could be this:

```
<?php 
   if (is_single()){
      echo "ga('set', contentGroup1, '".get_the_author()."');\n";
      $category = get_the_category();
      if ($category && !empty($category[0]->cat_name)){
         echo "ga('set', contentGroup2, '".$category[0]->cat_name."');\n”;
      }
   }
?>
```

More information can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en

Comment: And what would the complete tracking look like then (incl. your part)?                                                     The normal tracking code is "<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>"